# aes cbc encrypt, decrypt result is diffrent(objecitve-c, c#)

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a code in c# for aes decryption

i want make same encryption result by objective-c

but i failed.. help me

i can fix objective-c code, what can i for this?

c# for decrypt

```cs
        private static readonly string AES_KEY = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
        private static readonly int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
        private static readonly int KEY_SIZE = 128;
        private static readonly int BLOCK_SIZE = 128;

        static public string Composite(string value)
        {
            using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
            using (MemoryStream ims = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(value), false))
            {
                aes.KeySize = KEY_SIZE;
                aes.BlockSize = BLOCK_SIZE;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_KEY);

                byte[] iv = new byte[aes.IV.Length];
                ims.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length);
                aes.IV = iv;

                using (ICryptoTransform ce = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ims, ce, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                using (DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(cs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                using (MemoryStream oms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                    for (int size = ds.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length); size > 0; size = ds.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length))
                    {
                        oms.Write(buf, 0, size);
                    }
                    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oms.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
```

objective-c for encrypt

```
- (NSString *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *plainData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *encryptedData = [plainData AES128EncryptWithKey:key];

    NSString *encryptedString = [encryptedData stringUsingEncodingBase64];

    return encryptedString;
}
```

```
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

static char encodingTable[64] =
{
   'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P',
   'Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f',
   'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v',
   'w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'
};

@implementation NSData (AESCrypt)

- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key
{
    // 'key' should be 16 bytes for AES128
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128 + 1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero( keyPtr, sizeof( keyPtr ) ); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof( keyPtr ) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc( bufferSize );

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt( kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCModeCBC | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted );
    if( cryptStatus == kCCSuccess )
    {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free( buffer ); //free the buffer
    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)base64Encoding
{
   const unsigned char   *bytes = [self bytes];
   NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:self.length];
   unsigned long ixtext = 0;
   unsigned long lentext = self.length;
   long ctremaining = 0;
   unsigned char inbuf[3], outbuf[4];
   unsigned short i = 0;
   unsigned short charsonline = 0, ctcopy = 0;
   unsigned long ix = 0;

   while( YES )
   {
      ctremaining = lentext - ixtext;
      if( ctremaining <= 0 ) break;

      for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
      {
         ix = ixtext + i;
         if( ix < lentext ) inbuf[i] = bytes[ix];
         else inbuf [i] = 0;
      }

      outbuf [0] = (inbuf [0] & 0xFC) >> 2;
      outbuf [1] = ((inbuf [0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((inbuf [1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
      outbuf [2] = ((inbuf [1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((inbuf [2] & 0xC0) >> 6);
      outbuf [3] = inbuf [2] & 0x3F;
      ctcopy = 4;

      switch( ctremaining )
      {
         case 1:
            ctcopy = 2;
            break;
         case 2:
            ctcopy = 3;
            break;
      }

      for( i = 0; i < ctcopy; i++ )
         [result appendFormat:@"%c", encodingTable[outbuf[i]]];

      for( i = ctcopy; i < 4; i++ )
         [result appendString:@"="];

      ixtext += 3;
      charsonline += 4;
   }
   return [NSString stringWithString:result];
}
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------

### ------------------------------------------------------------

---

Comment: Your C# seems to include a decompression step. Your ObjC doesn't seem to include a compression step. What is `DeflateStream` doing?

Comment: @Rob Napier  thanks bro yes that seems to compressing method, i cant find same method in objective-c do you know how to fix this code?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_data_with_buffer_compression?language=objc   Apple calls the DEFLATE algorithm "COMPRESSION_ZLIB"